# Question in Flex (parser)

Tags: flex-lexer

I want to ask you a question about Flex, the program for parsing code. 
Supposing I have an instruction like this one, in the rules part:

```
"=" BEGIN(attribution);

<attribution>{var_name} { fprintf(yyout, "="); ECHO; }

<attribution>";" BEGIN(INITIAL);
```

{var_name} is a regular expression that matches a variable's name, and all I want to do is to copy at the output all the attribution instructions, such as 
    a = 3; 
or 
    b = a;

My rule though cannot write with fprintf the left member of the attribution, but only 
    = 3; 
or 
    =a;

One solution for that might be that, after I make the match "=" and I am in the attribution state, to go 2 positions back as to get the left operand as well. 
How can I do that in Flex?

Comment: Flex is not a parser. It's a lexer generator.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using flex for syntactical analysis?

What you are doing sounds like a bison stuff not a flex job.
You'll be able to store previous token.

If you still want to use flex, you can use the / pattern. 
Using this may lead to inefficiencies and the lexer can be bogus; it depends of the whole rule set.

```
{var_name}/"=" { ECHO; BEGIN(attribution); }
```

See [the flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html).